# How do I access the actionLink parameter in a C# class file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Given the HTML helper ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "AboutUs", "Public", null, null)
```

How do I access the actionLink parameter in a C# class file?

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking how you can call `Html.ActionLink()` in a file that is not a view?

Comment: Unclear question. Please explaine what you want to get as a result.

Comment: I know the question is unclear. I find the Razor docs to be pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionLink` is defined in the `LinkExtensions` class in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.  It is an extension method off of the `HtmlHelper` class.

In order to call the method from a regular class you would need an instance of the `HtmlHelper` class, but then you would just call it the same:

```
var link = htmlHelper.ActionLink("About Us", "AboutUs", "Public", null, null)
var linkHtml = link.ToHtmlString();
```

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, as it is accurate. Instantiating `HtmlHelper` outside of a view is possible (though it is a bit of work): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084523/how-do-you-create-an-htmlhelper-outside-of-a-view-in-asp-net-mvc-2-0

Comment: So, I can call it from an instance instantiated on the Razor template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you should be able to call it on any instance of the `HtmlHelper` class, such as the `Html` property of a Razor view.